# Is this a Context Free Language?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I got this question on my final exam: Is the following language context-free?

$$ L = \{w\bar w^R \mid  w\in \{0,1\}^*   \}$$

**Notation**: 
The string $\bar w$  is obtained from $w$ by replacing all 0s with 1's and all 1's with 0's.  The string $\bar w^R$ is $\bar w$ in reverse order.

---

> I've thought about it being a context-free language, but I notice that
>   when you pump the string in the middle, the string will still be in the
>   language. (using pumping lemma)

I think it's context free. 
This is the context free grammar:

$$
S \to 0S1 \mid  1S0 \mid \varepsilon $$
(It's basically a palindrome, but both sides are exact opposites.)

Comment: What do you think? What have you tried to show that it is? Or that it isn't?

Comment: Ok, i'll show my work

Comment: Now can you argue (perhaps informally) why your grammar is correct?

Comment: alright. i'll add more. done.

Comment: Why rR and not just R? Does the small r mean anything?

Comment: You are right. Please post your thoughts as self-answer to you question.

Comment: @The Unfun Cat....yes, I already wrote what wr means. Someone just changed my question. So, now wr is w¯

Answer (score 2):

A Context free grammer is one in which LHS of atleast one of the productions is free from any terminal symbols (context). 
According to your production rule,it is clearly CFG.