# CFG for $L=\{w_1cw_2:w_1\neq w_2^{R}\}$

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

I am trying to construct a context-free grammar for the following language:
$$L=\{w_1cw_2:w_1\neq w_2^{R}\},$$
where words are over $\{a,b,c\}$.

I have tried to do this by taking the union of two sub-languages:

1. The length of $w_1$ is not equal to the length of $w_2$.
2. The lengths are equal.

For 1, I've already written the grammar. But I'm having difficulty with 2. In terms of a PDA I think non-determinism can solve this. However, what is the CFG for 2?
If I can find it, I will union 1 and 2 to get the final solution.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that.  Have you tried reading through [our reference material](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755) on this subject and applying it to your exercise?  The methods there should work.  Have you tried searching this site?  You can find some related questions; I wouldn't be surprised if the techniques used for them can be used for your exercise too.  http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/7224/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/22846/755, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/43008/755.

Comment: Have we not had this before?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint for part (2): work from the inside out. A string of the form $w_1cw_2$ where $|w_1|=|w_2|$ is "matched" ($w_1=w_2^R$) if and only if it is of the form

- $c$, or
- (any character $x$) ("matched" string) (character $x$)

Similarly, such a string is "unmatched" if and only it is of the form

- (any character) ("unmatched" string) (any character), or
- (any character $x$) ("matched" string) (any character $y\ne x$)

Thus, we can make a grammar where the "matched" strings are generated by
$$
M\rightarrow c\mid aMa\mid bMb\mid cMc
$$
We can make the "unmatched" strings ($w_1\ne w_2$) generated by similar productions, which I'll let you do, using the variable $U$. Finally, you want to generate "unmatched" strings, so $U$ will be the start variable for your grammar.